# Successfully created a task in Snowflake, but it does not show up when running "show tasks"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I am new to Snowflake and am trying to create my first task.

```
CREATE TASK task_update_table
WAREHOUSE = "TEST"
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 5 * * * America/Los_Angeles'
AS
INSERT INTO "TEST"."WEB"."SOME_TABLE" (ID,VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3)
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT 
ID
,VALUE1
,VALUE2
,VALUE3
FROM OTHER_TABLE
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM "TEST"."WEB"."SOME_TABLE")
)
SELECT      
ID,VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3
FROM CTE
```

I got a message that the task was created successfully

"Task task_update_table successfully created"

I then try to run show tasks in schema `SHOW TASKS IN "TEST"."WEB"` and get 0 rows as a result. What am I doing wrong? why is the task not showing?

I did all of this under sysadmin and was using the same warehouse, db and schema.

Answer (score 1):

There are some limitations around show commands that might be blocking you,
particularly *"SHOW commands only return objects for which the current user’s current role has been granted the necessary access privileges"*.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show.html#general-usage-notes

I suspect the task was created by a different role (therefore owned by a different role), or perhaps it was created in different database or schema.

To find it, I'd recommend running the following using a role such as ACCOUNTADMIN.

```
show tasks in account;
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM   TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())))
WHERE "name" = 'TASK_UPDATE_TABLE';
```

While testing and learning in Snowflake, it is critical you set your session "context" correctly, using commands like this:

```
USE ROLE my_role_here;
USE WAREHOUSE my_warehouse_here;
USE DATABASE my_database_here;
USE SCHEMA my_schema_here;
```

Doing those four commands, or setting defaults for them for your user will help you tremendously when learning.

I hope this helps...Rich

Comment: Thank you so much, Rich! The strange thing is that I created a task and then ran the show command immediately after without changing the role, db or schema. I tried following your advice and still nothing, 0 rows. Could it be that tasks are not available on the standard instance level? or should I contact support?

Comment: regarding standard edition - the tasks and streams features should be available to your deployment - see https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-editions.html#data-pipelines.    Did you try to run the show command with a role with elevated privileges (e.g. ACCOUNTADMIN)?   If you have and cannot find the task, then a support request would probably be my next recommendation.